# How to filter without using lambda (lang=racket)

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

Suppose I want to make a function which takes only one parameter (lst) and "filters" the list.

```
(define (my-fn lst)
(filter (...) lst))
```

Without using lambdas or recursion, is there a possible way to implement this function? I do understand the function `curry` can be used, but not sure exactly how.

Comment: You need a lambda for a parameter to your function...

Comment: This is _literally_ the previous question someone asked, you should search the existing questions before asking ;)

Comment: I'll be sure to double check existing questions.